# How to have the Header show different content on different pages?

Tags: menus, navigation

I made a Navigation (primary) via Appearance->Menus which navigates the user to anchor tags on the side, but I also have subpages, where I want a different navigation - only with my 'Home'-button in it. Which would mean I need to get rid of the other navigation points.
I did create another sub-navigation for the subpages, but don't know how to get it up.

My `header.php` shows me
`<php if (has_nav_menu ( 'primary') ) : ?>`
Can i just do an `else` with another navigation?

My Theme only supports one menu though ...

Big thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Welcome to site :) May you please clarify your question by explaining how your theme is currently laid out? For example, is your primary navigation in `header.php` or elsewhere...? Also, the different navigation you referred to: how different is it? (1) entirely different, or (2) adds a one or two links to the original nav, or (3) removes one or two links...? The more information you can provide the better (and faster) answers you will get from the community here. And don't worry about being a beginner: everyone here was once a beginner.

Comment: PS. You can edit your question to add the details there instead of responding to this comment, that way the information will be more visible to readers.

Comment: Thanks for the help on the edit, @jsmod!
And thanks for the nice words~

Comment: Glad to assist :) Please bear with me as I ask more questions: I noticed you mentioned your theme supports one menu, yet you created a sub-navigation for your other pages. Do you mean you hard coded that sub-navigation menu in your `header.php` file? If yes, you might want to consider [creating a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) **before** you continue because _any_ changes you make to the original (parent) theme will be gone when that theme is updated. A child theme will preserve the changes you make.

Comment: A quick an easy way to get a link for **Home** on all pages and your `primary` menu on only the index/home page is suggested in an [answer below by Monkey Puzzle](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/332892/160457). If that works for you, please mark it as answered so others searching for the same thing can easily see the solution.

Comment: But if you later find you need more menus with more links, you can still accomplish that with [Monkey Puzzel's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/332892/160457) or [Hồ Trọng Linh Ân's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/332895/160457). In both cases though, be sure to use a child theme that can [register extra menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus). It seems like a lot, but it is very simple to accomplish and tutorials are plentiful. Plus, you can always come back to this website to ask if you try something and it doesn't work as expected. :)

Comment: I luckily worked in a child theme before, saved my work at least one time now!
@Monkey Puzzle's answer helped me heaps, marked it as solution~

And about your question: I tried hardcoding the sub-nav, but ... wasn't implementing it good enough it seems ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need another Navigation menu.

How about something like this:

```
<?php if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0 ) { 
   // we know we are on a sub/child page now...
   // PS. another way to handle this would be to check if you were on a particular page template or particular page ids etc.
?>
<a class="awesome-button" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">Go home!</a>
<?php 
    // just show a link Home for the subpages...
} else {
   // now we are NOT on a subpage, so show the Primary nav menu...
   wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'primary') );
} ?>
```

Comment: This should go in `header.php` of the current theme (if it is an original theme not from the repository) or `header.php` of the child theme in other cases, correct?

Comment: You can put this in header.php or sidebar.php or any of your page templates. It all depends how your theme works and where you want it to show!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was out cold for personal reasons.
Big thx for the help, was lost at first but after I understood how and why to make subpages and not all single pages it went rather smooth! :)
Now just needa figure out a way on how to best implement that home button, but the way is set~

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Kalex you can use the `get_header` for your custom header.php file. You can get the example code from here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/ .

The combination of [Template Name](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) with [Custom Header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) is very make sense for this case (if I understand right your question).